# Methods for dealing with gas pains?

Tags: pain, gastroenterology, flatulence-gas-fart, colon

The Internet is full of advice on how to *prevent* flatulence (e.g. diet changes), but no serious tips on how to get rid of gas once it's set in.

Gas trapped in the colon can cause significant pain. Are there any methods to help move gas along and expel it once it builds up in the colon?

Answer (score 5):

Yes, there are ways.

- First, make sure the stomach is not squeezed by a tight belt or similar.
- One can support gas movement by massaging the belly.
- Since some gases tend to move upwards, changing one's position in a way that the exit is elevated can help (*e.g.*  doggy style).
- Some herbs also help a bit, for example a spoon of caraway filled with hot water in a cup and drink after 5-10 mins.
- A hot-water bottle reduces the cramps.

http://www.brighamandwomens.org/Patients_Visitors/pcs/nutrition/services/healtheweightforwomen/special_topics/intelihealth0504.aspx

for infants:

http://www.webmd.com/parenting/baby/features/infant-gas

Comment: This post has the makings of a very good answer, but here on Health, we [*strongly encourage*](http://meta.health.stackexchange.com/q/1) using references. They are the only way in which we can tell if information is reliable or not. If you are struggling to find good sources, check out, [What are reliable sources?](http://meta.health.stackexchange.com/q/112) If you want to learn more about our site's stance on answers without references, check out, [Should answers without references be immediately deleted?](http://meta.health.stackexchange.com/q/283) Thanks :)

Comment: I do understand that personal experience is not enough  on this site. However, after scrolling through the list of  reliable sources given on your link, I wonder if I will be able to find a good resource about this topic. I'll give it a try...

Comment: So far, i didn't find a paper. The topic is  discussed as a side effect of other diseases (lactose intolerance, irritable bowel syndrome), but only as a side note. Since I'm not affiliated with any medical institute, my access to journals is limited. @michaelpri: what is the common procedure? Should I delete my answer? Or edit it somehow to underline the lack of reliable sources?

Comment: Great info (+1) and it's so refreshing to see someone who just doesn't dismiss the references policy. Don't delete the answer, Dave's edit gave you sufficient references. Hope to see more answers from you :-).

Answer (score 3):

In addition to the home-remedies suggested by Marzipanherz - the warm bottle is a good one - there are pharmacological therapeutic options out there.

**Gas-X, Mylicon, others** <sup>[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simethicone#Availability)</sup>

Simethicone (an inert mixture of polymers stabilized with silicon dioxide)

Gas can become trapped in small bubbles in the gut. Simethicone is known for its ability to collapse bubbles by forming a thin layer on their surface.<sup>[2](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/8083482)</sup> This decreases the volume of gas in the GI tract, but it's unclear if this has a therapeutic effect.

**BEANO**

(alpha-galactosidase preparation)

Another option is to diminish the creation of new gas if your gas is being caused by a particular kind of food, in this case, foods containing the trisaccharide raffinose.<sup>[3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raffinose)</sup> Foods containing raffinose include things like beans, cabbage, brussels, sprouts. We can't digest this on our own, so it ferments in our stomachs and causes gas. The compound α-GAL in BEANO breaks raffinose down to galactose, which we can digest.

References

1: [A more comprehensive list of simethicone containing drugs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simethicone#Availability)

2: [Mechanism of antifoaming action of simethicone.](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/8083482)

3: [Wikipedia: Raffinose](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raffinose)

Answer (score 1):

You should try with Mint leaves and peppermint tea that's will help you a lot , but try with natural leaves not the one that sell in the store

Comment: Welcome to Health.SE. Since health is an important topic, the site has a strict policy that **all answers** should be [backed up with reliable references](https://health.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1/should-we-require-references-to-back-up-all-answers) in order to provide the community with the means to assess the merit of the answer, regardless of the reader's background. *See [this list of reliable sources](https://health.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/112/what-are-reliable-sources)*. If you still have trouble with this, feel free to visit the [help].